# Storing a function name in object and calling it later

Tags: javascript

I am working on a single page application, and I've so far successfully created a system that easily lets me switch between pages, now I think I need a way to call specific functions when opening a certain page.

For each page I have a `function` declared, for example `#page1` has `page1_func`, `#page2` has `page2_func` and so on.

The pages are all stored in this fashion

```
var appPages  = {
    "page1": {
        "id": "#page1",
        "title": "Page 1 Title",
        "callback": page1_func
    },

    "page2": {
        "id": "#page2",
        "title": "Page 2 Title",
        "callback": page2_func
    }
};
```

There's another function that takes care of the navigation, which when called with fetches the information about that page i.e its `title` and `id` to update the DOM.

I also want that function to actually be able to call the functions that's in the page's `callback` property.

```
function NavigateToPage( page )  {
    ..
    ..
    appPages[ page ].callback( "some args" );
}
```

However this isn't working as I am declaring functions at the end of the script, but as far as I know declare a function at the end or the beginning it doesn't matter, it is always available though in my case the console tells me the `page1_func` isn't defined.

I need help with a better solution to this problem

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted. They will be available even if you declare them eof

Comment: Objects can have functions which are called methods. Just define a function within the object. and call it as if you were getting a variable in dot or bracket notation.

Comment: If you're declaring them in different `<script>` tags... I'm not sure.

Comment: @user202729 Yes, and that turned out to be the problem, placing them in the file works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is works though.

```js
const appPages  = {
  page1: {
    id: '#page1',
    title: 'Page 1 Title',
    callback: page1_fn,
  },

  page2: {
    id: '#page2',
    title: 'Page 2 Title',
    callback: page2_fn,
  }
};

function triggerCallback(page) {
  appPages[page].callback('args...');
}

triggerCallback('page1');

function page1_fn(arg) {
  document.write(arg);
}

function page2_fn(arg) {
  document.write(arg);
}
```

Comment: This does work. I moved my function declarations in the same file as the one which creates the `appPages` object and it now works, I think the problem is with having those in different files.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Where did you put the page1_fn or page2_fn in the HTML file?

Comment: I put it in another JS file. I put `appPages` object in `main.js` file and `page1_fn` in another JS file `pages.js`

Comment: @DeepakKamat Call your `pages.js` above the `main.js` one. I did that and it is working for me.